# Evaluating $\lim_{t \to 0} \left(\int_0^1[bx+a(1-x)]^t \mathrm dx \right)^{1/t}$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

$0 \lt a \lt b,$ find

> $$\lim_{t \to 0} \left(\int_0^1[bx+a(1-x)]^t \mathrm dx \right)^{1/t}$$

I think substituting $(b-a)x+a=u$  will make
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to 0}\left(\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bu^t\ \mathrm du\right)^{1/t}
=&\,\lim_{t \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\,\Bigl[\frac {u^{t+1}}{t+1}\Bigr]_a^b\right)^{1/t}\\ 
=&\,\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{b^{t+1}}{t+1}-\frac{a^{t+1}}{t+1}\right)\right)^{1/t}
\end{align*}$$

This is where I got trouble, how can I evaluate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim_{t\to0}\bigg(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}u^{t}dt\bigg)^{\frac{1}{t}}=e^{\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln\big(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}u^{t}dt\big)}{t}}=e^{\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln\big(\frac{1}{(b-a)(t+1)}(b^{t+1}-a^{t+1})\big)}{t}}$

By L'hopital's rule we get that:

$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln\big(\frac{1}{(b-a)(t+1)}(b^{t+1}-a^{t+1}\big)}{t}$

$=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(b-a)(t+1)}{b^{t+1}-a^{t+1}}((b^{t+1}\ln(b)-a^{t+1}\ln(a))(b-a)(t+1))-(b^{t+1}-a^{t+1})(b-a))\frac{1}{(b-a)^{2}(t+1)^{2}}=\frac{b\ln(b)-a\ln(a)}{(b-a)}-1$.

Hence the limit to the original question is $e^{\frac{b\ln(b)-a\ln(a)}{b-a}-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution was nice until you get

$$ L := \lim_{t\to 0} \left( \frac{1}{b-a} \frac{b^{t+1} - a^{t+1}}{t+1} \right)^{1/t}. $$

But you cannot put the limit inside as there is still the power $1/t$ to the outer parenthesis, which clearly depends on $t$. In this case, write

$$ b^{t} = e^{t\log b} = 1 + t \log b + \cdots $$

and likewise for $a^{t}$. Then

\begin{align*}
L
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \left( \frac{1}{b-a} \frac{b - a + (b\log b - a\log a)t + \cdots }{t+1} \right)^{1/t} \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{(1+t)^{1/t}} \left( 1 + \frac{b\log b - a\log a}{b-a} t + \cdots \right)^{1/t}.
\end{align*}

But we know that

$$ \lim_{t\to 0} (1 + xt)^{1/t} = e^{x}. $$

Therefore we have

$$ L = \exp\left( \frac{b\log b - a\log a}{b-a} - 1 \right). $$

Comment: Ah, that was my mistake and thank you very much. But I can't understand why $b^t=1+tlogb+~,$and from where $(blogb-aloga)$came. Really sorry asking these, hope I get better soon..

Comment: sos440 was taylor expanding $b^{t}$ and $a^{t}$ at $t=0$. The first order term for the difference of the two series will be $(b\log(b)-a\log(a))t$.

Comment: You made me recall what taylor expanding is, which was forgottten for a long time.Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

As long as $0\lt a\le f(x)\le b\lt\infty$ on $[0,1]$,
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac1t\left(f(x)^t-1\right)=\log(f(x))
$$
converges uniformly on $[0,1]$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to0}\left(\int_0^1f(x)^t\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/t}
&=\lim_{t\to0}\left(1+t\int_0^1\frac1t\left(f(x)^t-1\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\left(1+t\int_0^1\log\left(f(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/t}\\[6pt]
&=e^{\int_0^1\log\left(f(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry but why can we suppose $0 \lt a \le f(x) \le b \lt \infty$??

Comment: @J.H.: That is a condition I am putting on $f$. In the question at hand, $f(x)=bx+a(1-x)$ satisfies $0\lt a\le f(x)\le b$.